# Seperate Realm Bool data in 2 sections Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm, sections

Good day! I have a little problem. I want to seperate data from Realm DB by Bool value (true and false). If Bool data currencyStatusCode == true then show currencyName, currencyCode and balance at first tableview section "Active accounts", if Bool data currencyStatusCode == false then in to second section "Inactive accounts". As well as I add image of DB look. Will be very appreciate for your help.

```
var sections = ["Active accounts", "Inactive accounts"]

@IBOutlet weak var accountManagerTableView: UITableView!


let realm = try? Realm()
let accounts = try! Realm().objects(currencyAccounts.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "currencyID")
var accountManager: currencyAccounts?
var accountsRecord: Results<currencyAccounts> {
    get {
        return realm!.objects(currencyAccounts.self)
    }
}
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sections[section]
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return accounts.count

 /*   switch (section) {
    case 0:


            return accounts.count
     break;


    case 1:



            return accounts.count
            break;

    default:
        break;

    }

return section
   */


    }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = accountManagerTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "activeCurrencyCell", for: indexPath) as! accountManagerTableViewCell

    let sortingtInTableView = realm?.objects(currencyAccounts.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "currencyID", ascending: true)
    let currentUserBalances = sortingtInTableView![indexPath.row]


            cell.currencyFullName.text = currentUserBalances.currencyName
            cell.currencyTitle.text = currentUserBalances.currencyCode
            cell.selectedAccountBalance.text = String(currentUserBalances.currencyBalance)


    return cell

}
```

[Realm DB data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvfjV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use filter again Realm object itself. Please refer [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) for more details.
Please find the code to filter active and inactive accounts:

```
let realm = try! Realm()

let activeAccounts = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("currencyStatusCode = true").sorted(byKeyPath: "currencyID")


// Persist your data easily
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(activeAccounts)
}


let realm = try! Realm()

let inactiveAccounts = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("currencyStatusCode = false").sorted(byKeyPath: "currencyID")


// Persist your data easily
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(inactiveAccounts)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! With switch statement, like in my code below it works correctly.